# use ID3 tag to collect information

Tags: tags, mp3, encapsulation, id3

I'm playing around with a .mp3 file and I'd like to imbed some code that prompts the listener for information (i was thinking a javascript popup) when the file is played.  I've been reading up on ID3 tags and there seems to be some neat functionality built into the 'Audio Encryption' or possibly into the 'Generate Encapsulate Object' frames, but I cannot seem to find any good examples.  I am assuming that if the tags can contain links I should be able to collect some data when the file is played.

Comment: This would have to be a feature of the player.  Are you in control of the player?

Answer (score 1):

No, ID3 in general does not support this. Only ID3v2, i.e. in versions 2.3.0 and 2.4.0 you could use

- a WXXX frame, see https://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#User_defined_URL_link_frame while
- a GEOB frame you might mean is more like an attachment for files, see https://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#General_encapsulated_object

How you're able to extract frames (let alone ID3v2 in general) out of an MP3 file with JavaScript is another problem.